# check if a value exists group by id in R

Tags: r, group-by, exists

I want to define a variable new_var by the following criteria:

For each id, if exist reference=1, then new_var=1; else new_var=0, for exemple:

```
id      reference 
A            0   
A            1     
B            0   
B            0
```

Create a  `new_var`, the table looks like this:

```
id      reference     new_var
A            0          1
A            1          1
B            0          0
B            0          0
```

I only know that I can use the statement `case when` in SAS, but in R how to do this?

Comment: `df$new_var <- ave(df$reference, df$id, FUN = any)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks, that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option with `transform`

```
transform(df1, new_var = as.integer(id %in% id[reference>0]))
#   id reference new_var
#1  A         0       1
#2  A         1       1
#3  B         0       0
#4  B         0       0
```